# bash - expanding a string containing environment variable references

Tags: bash, shell, unix, environment-variables

I'm using a `bash` shell. I have some values from my `env` that I want to extract and assign those values to a variable. I also need to split it at the `=` sign.  What's the best utility for this using bash?

I basically need to create a string with these values stripping out the delimter as well:

```
echo -e "This is my $KEY and my profile is $PROFILE"
This is my Ru2cXJbgWQ0wdtKBGbS5/nVQvGo and my profile is foobar
```

Result:

```
-bash-4.1$ echo -e "This is my $KEY"
This is my
-bash-4.1$ env | grep KEY
KEY=Ru2cXJbgWQ0wdtKBGbS5/nVQvGo
```

Example:

```
$ env | grep KEY
KEY=Ru2cXJbgWQ0wdtKBGbS5/nVQvGo

$ env | grep DEFAULT_PROFILE
DEFAULT_PROFILE=foobar
```

Comment: If they're in your environment they're already variables. You can just use `$KEY` or `$DEFAULT_PROFILE`.

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). If you can describe what you're trying to DO with these data -- what your end goal is -- we can probably help you better.

Comment: `env` is an external program, so is `grep`, they are not part of `bash` and you don't need either.  `echo $KEY` or `echo $DEFAULT_PROFILE`.

Comment: After the edit, what is the problem with `echo -e "This is my $KEY and this is my $DEFAULT_PROFILE"`?  Does that fail?

Comment: What does `printenv KEY` print?

Comment: @noober `printf "%s\n" "${KEY}"` prints nothing, but `env | grep KEY` has a result. Please, update the question with whole output of `env`, plus the result of `declare -p KEY`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To complement [Anthony Geoghegan's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36924963/45375), which shows that Bash *automatically* represents environment variables as *shell* variables<sup>[1]</sup>:

In short: **the fact that `env | grep KEY` returns `KEY=Ru2cXJbgWQ0wdtKBGbS5/nVQvGo` does NOT necessarily mean that an environment variable named `KEY` exists**.

It is *conceivable* that the `grep` matches you're getting are matches of *other* environment variables' *values* or even the last line of multi-line variable *name*.   <sup>Thanks, [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner).</sup>

While environment variable and values are *typically* single-line, they don't have to be. An example is Bash's own ability to export *functions*, whose typically *multi-line* definitions are exported as the values of specially named environment variables.

---

To **verify that a given (Bash) *shell* variable is indeed based on an *environment* variable**, use:

```
declare -p KEY  # example with variable name 'KEY'
```

If `KEY` is indeed an environment variable, you'll see (using your example):

```
declare -x KEY="Ru2cXJbgWQ0wdtKBGbS5/nVQvGo"
```

Note the `-x`, which indicates an *exported* variable, which is synonymous with being an *environment* variable.

By contrast:

- If `KEY` is a *shell* variable that isn't also an environment variable, the `-x` will be missing.
- if `KEY` is neither a shell variable nor an environment variable, you'll see an error message.

---

[anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava), in a comment on the question, demonstrates a **shell-independent way to test if an environment variable is defined**:

```
printenv KEY  # prints value of env. var. 'KEY'
```

An exit code of `0` tells you that the variable exists (even if it is has no value).

Note that `printenv` is an external utility that is not POSIX-compliant; it does, however, come with both Linux and BSD/OSX.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Note that by using Bash's own string expansion (interpolation of double-quoted strings), what gets expanded is not only *environment* variable references, but also shell-*only* variable references.  *GNU* utility `envsubst`, by contrast, allows you to restrict expansion to environment variables.

Comment: It's also possible for `KEY` to be the last line of a multiline *name*; an environment string can contain newlines prior to the `=`.

Comment: ok, i removed the `-e` and it worked! just doing `echo $KEY` will give me my value

Comment: @noober: Glad to hear it, but, unless there's a bug in Bash v4.1., the presence or absence of `-e` should make _no_ difference in your case.
`-e` would only make a difference if your variable values contained escape sequences such as `\n`.

Answer (score 3):

When Bash starts, each environment variable that it inherits is automatically created as a shell variable aka parameter. From the Bash man page:

> When a program is invoked it is given an array of strings called the environment.  This is a list of name-value pairs, of the form `name=value`.
>
> The  shell  provides  several  ways to manipulate the environment.  On invocation, the shell scans its own environment and creates a parameter for each name found, automatically marking it for export to child processes.

If `KEY` and `PROFILE` are environment variables, running

```
echo -e "This is my $KEY and my profile is $PROFILE"
```

should print the desired response.